# How to update multiple server code at one time

Tags: svn, server

I have multiple server on each server i have hosted my code and installed svn on that.

so my question was that if i have change something in code then i have to go each and every server to pull that change code. To over come to that problem i have written script to take update code from svn but the problem is again i have to login each server to run that script to is there any solution so that if i push code on my svn then the other server automatically pull code from my global svn repository.

Answer (score 0):

There are two to approach this that I've used:

1. Push your code out from Subversion, rather than pull it. Create a [post-commit hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) which triggers an update on each of your servers.
2. Utilize a Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment system to either push your changes out from a central location that monitors the repository, or has a service running on each server to poll the repository for changes and pull them down as needed.